# grid-row, не могу понять почему не работает

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, css-grid

Есть простой код: https://codepen.io/Vdodovych/pen/VQoYJy

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.items {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.items div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.items div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.items div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: brown;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items grid">
  <div class="grid item">item-1</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-2</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-3</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-4</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-5</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-6</div>
</div>
```

По моей логике блок `item-4` должен занимать `2fr` по высоте (и вторую и третью линию одновременно), но почему-то так не происходит.
Вот тут:

```
.items div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}
```

Почему не сработало и как лечить?

Comment: Подобная конструкция на gird-template-areas не работает также

Comment: Ожидаемый результат: https://youtu.be/iNPE0zGucTo?t=2819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Высота блоков "жестко" задана, поэтому и не реагирует 4-ый блок.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.items {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.items div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.items div:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.items div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background-color: brown;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items grid">
  <div class="grid item">item-1</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-2</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-3</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-4</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-5</div>
  <div class="grid item">item-6</div>
</div>
```